# How to divide image and text with diagonal line in html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem when dividing image and text in HTML.

```
#################################
#  __________________________   #
# |           |              |  #
# |          |               |  #
# |  text   |       IMAGE    |  #
# |        |                 |  #
# |_______|__________________|  #
#                               #
#################################
```

My code like this:

```
<div class="container" style="height: 600px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p style="text-align: left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quam repellat, rem possimus porro quisquam.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Will creates text and image.
But I don't know how to draw like this.

You can see real image at here:

[image]

Comment: `transform: skew()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the property [**`shape-outside`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) along with [**`clip-path`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to achieve this result.

```css
body,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  height: 100vh;
}
.img-container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  float: right;
  background: url(http://fillmurray.com/1000/1000) no-repeat center center / cover;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="img-container"></div>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla pellentesque orci id elit mollis luctus. Integer tincidunt euismod lectus sodales convallis. Pellentesque bibendum libero turpis, ac hendrerit ante maximus et. Cras interdum tortor id metus
    hendrerit volutpat.
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Support is not that great so make sure to check the browsers that support these properties:

- [`shape-outside` browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside)
- [`clip-path` browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

---

You can use this [**tool**](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to generate different values for the `polygon()` CSS function.

Comment: Thanks, @Ricky_Ruiz, I did it. Current, I have other problem. Is text not fit with parent div is skew. Can you help me? My question at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519832/how-to-fix-content-with-div-skew

Comment: In your example, the text is not over into image. Each element in a tag separate. But my code seem not like this.

Comment: @vanloc Do you need to support Internet Explorer?

Comment: This optional. But I need two version IE and other browser. Thanks you because you edited my question to easy read.