# How to fix content with div skew?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently transforming a `<div>` element using the `skewX(-18deg)` value, the problem is when I insert text into it I cannot prevent it from overflowing.

The element inside the skewed container is transformed back to normal using `skewX(18deg)`.

The final result should look like this:

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var curPage = 1;
  var numOfPages = $(".skw-page").length;
  var animTime = 1000;
  var scrolling = false;
  var pgPrefix = ".skw-page-";

  function pagination() {
    scrolling = true;

    $(pgPrefix + curPage).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage - 1)).addClass("inactive");
    $(pgPrefix + (curPage + 1)).removeClass("active");

    setTimeout(function() {
      scrolling = false;
    }, animTime);
  };

  function navigateUp() {
    if (curPage === 1) return;
    curPage--;
    pagination();
  };

  function navigateDown() {
    if (curPage === numOfPages) return;
    curPage++;
    pagination();
  };

  $(document).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      navigateUp();
    } else {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (scrolling) return;
    if (e.which === 38) {
      navigateUp();
    } else if (e.which === 40) {
      navigateDown();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #15181A;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.skw-pages {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
.skw-page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.skw-page__half {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
}
.skw-page__half--left {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-32.4vh, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-32.4vh, 100%, 0);
}
.skw-page__half--right {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(32.4vh, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(32.4vh, -100%, 0);
}
.skw-page__half--30 {
  width: 30%;
}
.skw-page__half--70 {
  width: 70%;
}
.skw-page.active .skw-page__half {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.skw-page__skewed {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 140%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-18deg);
  transform: skewX(-18deg);
  background: #000;
}
.skw-page__half--left .skw-page__skewed {
  left: -20%;
}
.skw-page__half--right .skw-page__skewed {
  right: -20%;
}
.skw-page__content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 30%;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(18deg);
  transform: skewX(18deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}
.skw-page__half--left .skw-page__content {
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.skw-page__half--right .skw-page__content {
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.skw-page.inactive .skw-page__content {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(18deg) scale(0.95);
  transform: skewX(18deg) scale(0.95);
}
.skw-page__heading {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.skw-page__description {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.skw-page__link {
  color: #FFA0A0;
}
.skw-page-1 .skw-page__half--left .skw-page__content {
  background: #292929;
}
.skw-page-1 .skw-page__half--right .skw-page__content {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/slider-2.jpg");
}
.skw-page-2 .skw-page__half--left .skw-page__content {
  background: #292929;
}
.skw-page-2 .skw-page__half--right .skw-page__content {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/sections-3.jpg");
}
.skw-page-3 .skw-page__half--left .skw-page__content {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/img-test.jpg");
}
.skw-page-3 .skw-page__half--right .skw-page__content {
  background: #292929;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skw-pages">

  <div class="skw-page skw-page-1 active">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left skw-page__half--30">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 1</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus harum qui, placeat fugit delectus maxime voluptatibus perspiciatis, quia sit itaque! Ut eum dicta quam minus earum beatae at iure perspiciatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Ex, ut. Fugit minima consequatur voluptatem commodi culpa, adipisci laborum qui vitae. Voluptas voluptates nihil ratione eaque labore perspiciatis, animi placeat eligendi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
            elit. Quibusdam libero, cupiditate asperiores tempora quos porro inventore? Praesentium aperiam deleniti nam a aliquid sequi ea perspiciatis error recusandae enim, dolorem quae.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right skw-page__half--70">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="skw-page skw-page-2">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left skw-page__half--30">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 2</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">Ok, ok, just one more scroll!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right skw-page__half--70">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="skw-page skw-page-3">
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--left skw-page__half--30">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skw-page__half skw-page__half--right skw-page__half--70">
      <div class="skw-page__skewed">
        <div class="skw-page__content">
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Epic finale</h2>
          <p class="skw-page__description">
            Feel free to check
            <a class="skw-page__link" href="http://codepen.io/suez/pens/public/" target="_blank">my other pens</a> and follow me on
            <a class="skw-page__link" href="https://twitter.com/NikolayTalanov" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here my pen:

See the Pen [New version - Scroll one page](http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301/pen/pNjGrB/) by Văn Lộc ([@r0ysy0301](http://codepen.io/r0ysy0301)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Comment: You might want to look into this - wrapping content into shapes with css http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-content-wrapping/

Comment: There is no cross browser compatible solution to this, let alone anything mobile friendly and responsive. It can be done if you use many many divs but I would not do it, unless paid very well for this.

Comment: Many `<divs>` of the content contain text? Can you suggest with a demo? Currently, I don't know the method to resolve my problem. I also tried the method of @skav, but it only applies to object geometry like the shape and not correct with my problem.

Comment: To align text on the slanted side, see : [Align text on slanted line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27876883/1811992)

Comment: If you want to got down the "many divs" road, I think it can be automated using javascript, though the final result will have a terrible markup. I suggest you follow @skav 's comment for the browsers that support it and then beutifully degrade for other browsers (split it vertically instead of diagonally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@skav link was a good direction, but for some reason shape-inside is much less reliable than shape-outside.

So here's how I solved this:[image]

you can insert a div in your description div and style it with an outershape to match the skewed image on the right. Obviously, you'd put the background to transparent, i made it green so you could see it's effect.

Also, for your image, using a clip-path would require less lines of code.
Putting your text in p tags made it more clear and adding ­ in words make the justified text prettier.

for html:

```
<div class="skw-page__content">
          <div class="triangle"></div>
          <h2 class="skw-page__heading">Page 1</h2>
          <div class="skw-page__description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con&shy;sect&shy;etur adi&shy;pisi&shy;cing elit. Accu&shy;sa&shy;mus ha&shy;rum qui, pla&shy;ceat fugit de&shy;lec&shy;tus ma&shy;xime volupta&shy;tibus perspi&shy;ciatis, quia sit it&shy;aque!</p>
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/142996/img-test.jpg" alt="random nice picture of a montain reflecting ine a blue lake"/>
            <p>Qui&shy;bus&shy;dam lib&shy;ero, cupi&shy;di&shy;ta&shy;te aspe&shy;rio&shy;res tem&shy;pora quos porro in&shy;ven&shy;tore? Prae&shy;sen&shy;tium ape&shy;riam dele&shy;ni&shy;ti nam a a&shy;li&shy;quid sequi ea perspi&shy;ciatis error recu&shy;sandae enim, do&shy;lorem quae.</p>
          </div>
```

for css:

```
  &__description {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    hyphens: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0;
}
img{
      min-width: 0px;
      max-width: 75%;
      min-height: 0px;
      margin: 2% 0;
      clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 78% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }

.triangle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    shape-margin: 0 0 0 2%;
    clip-path: polygon(98% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
    shape-outside: polygon(95% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
    background: green;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
}
```

Voilà :)

Comment: Merci. Bonne journée! :)